# Can't enable Maps SDK for Android in cloud console

Tags: android, google-maps, google-cloud-platform, google-places, google-directions-api

I'm facing this issue while enabling the Maps SDK for Android in cloud console.

[image][`https://console.cloud.google.com/`](https://console.cloud.google.com/)

It will throw the following errors; screenshot attached.

[image]

[image]

I got the error that I can't complete this transaction. After that, when I click the form it will take me to some other page, here is the link https://support.google.com/pay/contact/account_verification

After I submit all my documents I'll get the following response from google:

[image]

They posted 28-48 hours we will contact but there is no response from google's end. Anyone facing these kind of issues? How can we resolve this issue? I'm facing this for 7 of my projects, this issue especially occurs for Indian accounts.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your billing account is based in India please refer to Google's FAQ here https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-india-faq

Answer (score 4):

If your billing account is based in India, please refer to Google's FAQ [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-india-faq).

> Google Maps Platform services cannot be billed through the same
>   billing account as Google Cloud Platform services. In order to
>   continue using Google Maps Platform, all customers with a billing
>   account in INR will need to create a new billing account for Maps and
>   then migrate their existing Maps projects under this new account.