# Google Maps API Billing not Enabled Error - Billing not open

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

I am adding a Google Map to a client's site. The problem is that I am getting the "Development Use Only" overlay on the map, although the billing is enabled for the said project. The Google Maps API checker shows successful API requests. But the browser console gives Billing not enabled error. One thing peculiar I found was that in Google Maps API overview it shows that **Billing Account is not open**. I think the error is because of this, but I am unable to figure out why it is not open. I am not getting any errors with payment, the project is associated with a Billing account, I even verified the respective domain, but still, the error.

[Google Billing Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brP7S.png)

[Project Associated with Billing Account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdNMl.png)

[Google Maps API Checker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5OtH.png)

[Browser Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUka4.png)

[Google Maps Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEdCf.png)

The code is similar to:

```
<script>
    function myMap() {
      var mapProp= {
        center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
        zoom:5,
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),mapProp);
      }
    </script>

   <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&callback=myMap"></script>
```

Comment: This is purely a guess going by your name, but it might be this https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-india-faq#bill-maps

Comment: You should open a support ticket with Google

Comment: Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58891318/maps-sdk-for-android-not-able-to-enable-in-console-cloud/59027297#59027297

Comment: @ecg8 yes, contacted the support. They informed the same.

Comment: i did not get it can you guys explain how you resolved the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if you are using an INR billing account. if you do, then you need to use/create a new one for USD to make it work.

Check the following documentation to learn more:

https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-india-migration#same

https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-india-faq#overview

Comment: yup, contact the support. They mentioned the same. It's working now. thank you.

Comment: i did not get it can you guys explain how you resolved the issue?

Comment: @warmachine basically in India Google has seperated billing for Maps platform. So, we had to separately create a seperate billing account for Google Maps. That solved the error.