# Distance matrix API returns error message

Tags: google-maps

I have been given project editor role for GCP project, I can see in https://console.cloud.google.com/billing/projects that the project has been mapped to a billing account, thus it shows billing account ID.

I tried test launch of a GCP instance to see if it is working. Distance matrix API has been enabled, an API key has been generated and tested distance matrix API however I am getting the following error message.

```
{
   "destination_addresses": [],
   "error_message": "You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started",
   "origin_addresses": [],
   "rows": [],
   "status": "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

Why is this error ? If Billing is not enabled I couldn't have launched a VM instance.

Comment: Do you have a billing account associated with the API key you are using with the Distance Matrix?

Comment: Yes, I do have an API key associated with the project linked with a Billing account. I created and deleted the API key to see if it makes any difference. Infact it worked once with postman but not with browser at that time.

Comment: If you're in India, please check out related thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58891318/maps-sdk-for-android-not-able-to-enable-in-console-cloud

Comment: Thank you ! The issue has resolved by creating a new billing account for Google maps by selecting Google Maps Platform instead of Google Cloud Platform and then linking that  Billing account with newly created project. API Key generated with that new project works.

Comment: Glad to hear & happy to help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you ! The issue has resolved by creating a new billing account for Google maps by selecting Google Maps Platform instead of Google Cloud Platform at the time of creating Billing Account and then linking that Billing account with the newly created project. API Key generated with that new project works. Working with Google Maps needs creation of separate Billing account unlike regular Google Cloud Platform Billing Account