# Places autocomplete api showing exception

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I am using Places autocomplete api and the problem I am facing that when I try to search any place by typing , it shows error as ->

[image]

Now my code is

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val apiKey = getString(R.string.api_key)

        if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
            Places.initialize(
                applicationContext,
                apiKey
            )
        }

        val placesClient =
            Places.createClient(this)
        gmap.setOnClickListener {
            onSearchCalled();
            //startActivity(Intent(this, Gmap::class.java))
        }

    fun onSearchCalled() { // Set the fields to specify which types of place data to return.
        val fields: List<Place.Field> = Arrays.asList(
            Place.Field.ID,
            Place.Field.NAME,
            Place.Field.ADDRESS,
            Place.Field.LAT_LNG,
            Place.Field.ADDRESS_COMPONENTS
        )
        // Start the autocomplete intent.
        val intent = Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
            AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, fields
        ).build(this)
        startActivityForResult(intent, AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        resultCode: Int,
        data: Intent?
    ) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val place =
                    Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data!!)
                Log.i(
                    "aaaaa",
                    "Place: " + place.name + ", " + place.id
                )
            } else if (resultCode == AutocompleteActivity.RESULT_ERROR) { // TODO: Handle the error.
                val status =
                    Autocomplete.getStatusFromIntent(data!!)
                Log.i("aaaa", status.statusMessage)
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) { // The user canceled the operation.
            }
        }
    }
```

I believe I followed everything according to [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#option_2_use_an_intent_to_launch_the_autocomplete_activity)
 and I am also attaching manifest and build.gradle dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

The Google Play Services version of the Places SDK for Android was [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration) in January 2019. So first of all, remove this line from your build.gradle dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
```

Secondly, make sure that you have [billing](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable?redirect=https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/start?dialogOnLoad%3Dbilling-enabled) enabled on your project, and that [Places API](https://cloud.google.com/console/apis/library/places-backend.googleapis.com) is also enabled.

I've just tested your code (with my valid API key and with the above gms dependency removed) and Place Autocomplete worked perfectly on my end. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi my main problem was the place autocomplete was showing suggestions when typed 3 letter, but showed error when typed more than that..which is still awkward..I removed the said dependency..

Comment: So i understand that it still doesn't work for you? Did you double check that billing is enabled on your project? Note that if you're in India you need to create a USD billing account. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58891318/maps-sdk-for-android-not-able-to-enable-in-console-cloud/59027297#59027297

Comment: yes I understand that billing needs to be enabled, but is this what is responsible for this weird behaviour? https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_vLbQk7XbCneEhTNkZ3ZDJXZmpaMG1uczhYMTh3MmdQVm80 and https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_vLbQk7XbCnczlfTlhoNU5fYl9Vdi1NNXRVRXpaSFJFY1NB

Comment: It could be yes. The error "can't load search results" means that you either haven't migrated (fixed now), have billing disabled, places API disabled, or your api key is wrongly restricted. Please double check these. Your code works for me so the issue is one of those. Keep me posted. :)

Comment: places api is enabled, api key is not restricted,only billing account is disabled

Comment: Then you know what the issue is and how to fix it. :)