# Places API - Unable to retreive suggestions in android

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, google-places-api, autosuggest

I am trying to create a autocomplete textview and the adapter being used is google API. When I type in the autocomplete textview, the result should have been places being suggested from what I had typed but I am getting no suggestions at all. Please help me out as I am a newbie. I tried to search couldn't find any questions based on this. Any help is appreciated. I am testing on my Oneplus 7T phone which runs on android 10. And I also have a stable internet connection.

The expected result should have places being suggested like this[image: places being suggested]

But in my case nothing is happening at all.

P.S. Followed - https://github.com/AhsanMunir/Google-Places-SDK-for-Android

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:id="@+id/main_first">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:text="@string/trip_planner"
                android:textSize="27sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_margin="7dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:text="@string/let_s_get_your_trip_started"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_margin="7dp"/>
            <!--
            <fragment android:id="@+id/start_off"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"
                android:layout_margin="7dp"/>
            <fragment android:id="@+id/destination"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"
                android:layout_margin="7dp"/>
               -->
            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:hint="Enter Starting Point" />

       <!--     <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/auto_dest"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:hint="Enter Destination" />  -->


        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/plan_trip_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/let_s_plan_your_trip"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    View view;
    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView,autodest;
    AutoCompleteAdapter adapter,adapter_dest;

    PlacesClient placesClient;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        view=findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
        Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermissions(

                        Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                ).withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
            @Override public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {/* ... */}
            @Override public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {/* ... */}
        }).check();
        MultiplePermissionsListener dialogMultiplePermissionsListener =
                DialogOnAnyDeniedMultiplePermissionsListener.Builder
                        .withContext(getApplicationContext())
                        .withTitle("INTERNET and GPS permission")
                        .withMessage("Both permissions are needed to help you better")
                        .withButtonText(android.R.string.ok)

                        .build();
        MultiplePermissionsListener snackbarMultiplePermissionsListener =
                SnackbarOnAnyDeniedMultiplePermissionsListener.Builder
                        .with(view, "Camera and audio access is needed to take pictures of your dog")
                        .withOpenSettingsButton("Settings")
                        .withCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onShown(Snackbar snackbar) {
                                // Event handler for when the given Snackbar is visible
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int event) {
                                // Event handler for when the given Snackbar has been dismissed
                            }
                        })
                        .build();

        String apiKey = getString(R.string.api_key);
        if(apiKey.isEmpty()){
            Log.d("Error","no api key found");
            return;
        }
        if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
            Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), apiKey);
        }
        PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);
        initAutoCompleteTextView()


    }
    private void initAutoCompleteTextView() {

        autoCompleteTextView = findViewById(R.id.auto);
        autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);
        autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(autocompleteClickListener);
        adapter = new AutoCompleteAdapter(this, placesClient);
        autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener autocompleteClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            try {
                final AutocompletePrediction item = adapter.getItem(i);
                String placeID = null;
                if (item != null) {
                    placeID = item.getPlaceId();
                }


                List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.ADDRESS
                        , Place.Field.LAT_LNG);

                FetchPlaceRequest request = null;
                if (placeID != null) {
                    request = FetchPlaceRequest.builder(placeID, placeFields)
                            .build();
                }

                if (request != null) {
                    placesClient.fetchPlace(request).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FetchPlaceResponse>() {
                        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(FetchPlaceResponse task) {
                            Log.d("TAG",task.getPlace().getName() + "\n" + task.getPlace().getAddress());
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.d("TAG", Objects.requireNonNull(e.getMessage()));
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };

}
```

Autocompleteadapter

```
public class AutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AutocompletePrediction> implements Filterable {

    private ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction> mResultList;
    private PlacesClient placesClient;

    AutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, PlacesClient placesClient) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1);
        this.placesClient = placesClient;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public AutocompletePrediction getItem(int position) {
        return mResultList.get(position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        AutocompletePrediction item = getItem(position);

        TextView textView1 = row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        TextView textView2 = row.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
        if (item != null) {
            textView1.setText(item.getPrimaryText(null));
            textView2.setText(item.getSecondaryText(null));
        }

        return row;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                // We need a separate list to store the results, since
                // this is run asynchronously.
                ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction> filterData = new ArrayList<>();

                // Skip the autocomplete query if no constraints are given.
                if (charSequence != null) {
                    // Query the autocomplete API for the (constraint) search string.
                    filterData = getAutocomplete(charSequence);
                }

                results.values = filterData;
                if (filterData != null) {
                    results.count = filterData.size();
                } else {
                    results.count = 0;
                }

                return results;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults results) {

                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    // The API returned at least one result, update the data.
                    mResultList = (ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    // The API did not return any results, invalidate the data set.
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
                // Override this method to display a readable result in the AutocompleteTextView
                // when clicked.
                if (resultValue instanceof AutocompletePrediction) {
                    return ((AutocompletePrediction) resultValue).getFullText(null);
                } else {
                    return super.convertResultToString(resultValue);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction> getAutocomplete(CharSequence constraint) {

        //Create a RectangularBounds object.
        RectangularBounds bounds = RectangularBounds.newInstance(
                new LatLng(-33.880490, 151.184363),
                new LatLng(-33.858754, 151.229596));


        final FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.Builder requestBuilder =
                FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.builder()
                        .setQuery(constraint.toString())
                        .setCountry("") //Use only in specific country
                        // Call either setLocationBias() OR setLocationRestriction().
                        .setLocationBias(bounds)
//                        .setLocationRestriction(bounds)
                        .setSessionToken(AutocompleteSessionToken.newInstance())
                        .setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.ADDRESS);

        Task<FindAutocompletePredictionsResponse> results =
                placesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(requestBuilder.build());


        //Wait to get results.
        try {
            Tasks.await(results, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException | TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (results.isSuccessful()) {
            if (results.getResult() != null) {
                return (ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction>) results.getResult().getAutocompletePredictions();
            }
            return null;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat extract

```
    2020-02-07 23:22:45.397 31414-31414/? W/le.trip_planne: OatFileAssistant(/data/app/com.example.trip_planner-rCbuIqxurZyXjkzsSKQxbQ==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk) Oat_file does not exist, will fallback to the original dex/jar file
2020-02-07 23:22:45.398 31414-31414/? W/le.trip_planne: Generation of oat file /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.trip_planner-rCbuIqxurZyXjkzsSKQxbQ==@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex not attempted because the vdex file /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.trip_planner-rCbuIqxurZyXjkzsSKQxbQ==@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.vdex could not be opened.
2020-02-07 23:22:45.398 31414-31414/? W/le.trip_planne: OatFileAssistant(/data/app/com.example.trip_planner-rCbuIqxurZyXjkzsSKQxbQ==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk) Oat_file does not exist, will fallback to the original dex/jar file
2020-02-07 23:22:45.400 31414-31414/? W/le.trip_planne: Generation of oat file /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.trip_planner-rCbuIqxurZyXjkzsSKQxbQ==@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex not attempted because the vdex file /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.trip_planner-rCbuIqxurZyXjkzsSKQxbQ==@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.vdex could not be opened.
2020-02-07 23:22:45.400 31414-31414/? W/le.trip_planne: OatFileAssistant(/data/app/com.example.trip_planner-rCbuIqxurZyXjkzsSKQxbQ==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk) Oat_file does not exist, will fallback to the original dex/jar file
2020-02-07 23:22:45.403 31414-31414/? W/le.trip_planne: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
2020-02-07 23:22:45.404 31414-31414/? I/chatty: uid=10364(com.example.trip_planner) identical 10 lines
2020-02-07 23:22:45.404 31414-31414/? W/le.trip_planne: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
2020-02-07 23:22:45.418 31414-31414/? I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
2020-02-07 23:22:45.526 31414-31414/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
2020-02-07 23:22:45.533 31414-31414/? V/Font: Change font:1
2020-02-07 23:22:45.533 31414-31414/? V/Font: Default family:android.graphics.Typeface@f0100b4
2020-02-07 23:22:45.537 31414-31441/? E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.trip_planner
2020-02-07 23:22:45.538 31414-31441/? E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
2020-02-07 23:22:45.538 31414-31441/? E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.trip_planner
2020-02-07 23:22:45.538 31414-31441/? E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
2020-02-07 23:22:45.603 31414-31414/? V/FlingOptimizerScroller: FlingOptimizerOverScroller Init
2020-02-07 23:22:45.624 31414-31414/? W/le.trip_planne: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-02-07 23:22:45.624 31414-31414/? W/le.trip_planne: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-02-07 23:22:45.773 31414-31414/? V/ViewRootImpl: The specified message queue synchronization  barrier token has not been posted or has already been removed
2020-02-07 23:22:45.796 31414-31437/? D/DecorView: onWindowFocusChangedFromViewRoot hasFocus: true, DecorView@7943d0[MainActivity]
2020-02-07 23:22:45.797 31414-31442/? I/AdrenoGLES: QUALCOMM build                   : bc92c36, I9e73322269
    Build Date                       : 08/28/19
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.27.02.00
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.8.1.R1.09.00.00.529.074
    Remote Branch                    : NONE
    Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
2020-02-07 23:22:45.797 31414-31442/? I/AdrenoGLES: Build Config                     : S P 8.0.8 AArch64
2020-02-07 23:22:45.800 31414-31442/? I/AdrenoGLES: PFP: 0x016ee187, ME: 0x00000000
2020-02-07 23:22:45.812 31414-31442/? W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
2020-02-07 23:22:45.856 31414-31414/? W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@c82a7fb
2020-02-07 23:22:45.879 31414-31414/? V/ViewRootImpl: The specified message queue synchronization  barrier token has not been posted or has already been removed
2020-02-07 23:22:45.909 31414-31414/? W/Choreographer: Already have a pending vsync event.  There should only be one at a time.
2020-02-07 23:22:46.024 31414-31414/? D/OnePlusJankManager:  Chor uploadMDM JANK_TYPE_ONCE mViewTitle = com.example.trip_planner/com.example.trip_planner.MainActivity--- jank level = 1
2020-02-07 23:22:46.097 31414-31437/? D/DecorView: onWindowFocusChangedFromViewRoot hasFocus: true, DecorView@7943d0[MainActivity]
2020-02-07 23:22:51.209 31414-31414/com.example.trip_planner I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2048 bytes, containing 1 windows, 11 views
2020-02-07 23:22:51.223 31414-31414/com.example.trip_planner E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
2020-02-07 23:22:51.228 31414-31414/com.example.trip_planner I/chatty: uid=10364(com.example.trip_planner) identical 2 lines
2020-02-07 23:22:51.228 31414-31414/com.example.trip_planner E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
2020-02-07 23:23:15.867 31414-31432/com.example.trip_planner D/DecorView: onWindowFocusChangedFromViewRoot hasFocus: true, DecorView@7943d0[MainActivity]
2020-02-07 23:23:16.943 31414-31554/com.example.trip_planner W/Filter: An exception occured during performFiltering()!
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.PlacesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.trip_planner.AutoCompleteAdapter.getAutocomplete(AutoCompleteAdapter.java:141)
        at com.example.trip_planner.AutoCompleteAdapter.access$000(AutoCompleteAdapter.java:29)
        at com.example.trip_planner.AutoCompleteAdapter$1.performFiltering(AutoCompleteAdapter.java:82)
        at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:236)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
2020-02-07 23:23:20.485 31414-31562/com.example.trip_planner W/Filter: An exception occured during performFiltering()!
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.PlacesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.trip_planner.AutoCompleteAdapter.getAutocomplete(AutoCompleteAdapter.java:141)
        at com.example.trip_planner.AutoCompleteAdapter.access$000(AutoCompleteAdapter.java:29)
        at com.example.trip_planner.AutoCompleteAdapter$1.performFiltering(AutoCompleteAdapter.java:82)
        at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:236)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
2020-02-07 23:23:20.936 31414-31562/com.example.trip_planner W/Filter: An exception occured during performFiltering()!
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.PlacesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.trip_planner.AutoCompleteAdapter.getAutocomplete(AutoCompleteAdapter.java:141)
        at com.example.trip_planner.AutoCompleteAdapter.access$000(AutoCompleteAdapter.java:29)
        at com.example.trip_planner.AutoCompleteAdapter$1.performFiltering(AutoCompleteAdapter.java:82)
        at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:236)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

Comment: Are you still having this issue? If so, I'll try to reproduce it today and will get back to you.

Comment: Hi evan, yeah I am still having trouble. Seems like internet is not being accessed at all.

Comment: Hi @evan any updates

Comment: Hey sorry i'm taking a break atm but will look into your issue next week as soon as im back! In the meantime please double check that your project is set up properly, i.e. billing is enabled, places api is enabled, your api key is properly restricted, migrated to the new places sdk and androidx.

Comment: Yeah sure I will double check the same, thanks evan

Comment: Wait i just checked your profile and you appear to be in India. If that's the case please check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/59027297/11742502

Comment: Hey evan, thanks a lot man. That was the issue. Kudos

Comment: Glad to hear & happy to help! :)