# Getting enable billing error on Google maps still getting billing is not enabled

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps API in my project : https://imobilenumbertracker.com, but even after enable the billing I am still getting the same error. Can you please assist how to proceed here.

I can see my billing account is enabled and free trial is started.

[image]

Comment: If you're in India please check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58891318/cant-enable-maps-sdk-for-android-in-cloud-console