# Google Places autocomplete API limit

Tags: google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

We are trying to use the Google's autocomplete API. ITs is already linked to Facebook payment account. but when we try to hit the API, it failed after 750 requests.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Kids%20jp%20nagar&key=APIKEY&fields=address_component,formatted_address

{"error_message": "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. If you did not set a custom daily request quota, verify your project has an active billing account:
 http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account",
 "predictions": [],
 "status": "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
 }
```

When we checked the limit it showed that maximum we can set it to only 750/per day in I AM section.

But in API's usage section it shows that API usage is Pay as you go. Is there any method to use more number of APIs in single day. We need to automate and cleanup the customer address database.

Comment: Are you based in India? If so please check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/59027297/11742502